# Extract last part of ID using regex or javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a component with an ID that is composed of a first static part and a second dynamic value, like this:

```
<div id="smallPlacardone">
```

Where: `smallPlacard` is static and `one` is passed using a variable.

Later in my code I want to use the dynamic part of the ID, namely `one`, but not the first static part `smallPlacard`, like this:

```
var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id");
$("#right"+clicked+"").show();
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: Change the part that generates random words that means nothing to a computer ("one").

Comment: So you want to click on `#rightone` and it should `show()` `#rightone`? That doesn't make sense...

Comment: @Tomalak You're right. I edited the `div ID`.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "smallPlacard" is static, then you can just remove it using the replace method:

```
var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id").replace(/smallPlacard/, '');
$("#right" + clicked).show();
```

Comment: @Paulo Janeiro /smallPlacard/ is a RegExp ;)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend working with delimiter chars and `split()`. It's easier to read and avoids the regex entirely:

```
<div id="smallPlacard_one">
```

and

```
var clicked = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1];
$("#right_" + clicked).show();
```

---

Alternatively something like this, which is more flexible because it does not rely on hidden conventions:

```
<div id="smallPlacard_one" data-show="#right_one">
```

and

```
var selector = $(this).data("show")
$(selector).show();
```

Comment: 1+ .. Definitely a better practice if the OP has control over their HTML.

Comment: Yes, thank you Tomalak. I already had accepted the other answer because it also works but this is, at least, cleaner.

Comment: You can, technically, accept a different answer (no endorsement implied whatsoever, I'm just telling you in case you have not been aware).

Comment: I wasn't. Although you're both out of my league I'll leave it as it is just because Josh has half your score and I'm also very grateful to him. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: Not at all, no worries. :)